# Android pass message from IntentService to Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-intentservice

I IntentService that I would like to send message to the main Activity it is nested in. I am using a broadcast receiver to broadcast the message I got from the IntentService as such:

```
public static class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.mypackage.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String text;
            text = intent.getStringExtra(RegistrationIntentService.PARAM_OUT);
            regid = text;
        }
    }
```

I have registered the receiver in the Oncreate method of the main Activity. How can I send the "text" in this case? It is weird that regid in this case is null while "text" has the string data I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When registering, this was what worked for me

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        receiver = new ResponseReceiver();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

as opposed to

```
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String text = intent.getStringExtra(RegistrationIntentService.PARAM_OUT);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //access the string text and send it to backend
                }
            });
        }
```

I hope this will help someone. Sending the string like suggested in the comments didn't work for me. I was getting nullpointerexception at that specific line where I assigned ma.regid = text;

Answer (score 1):

you can user result receiver with intent service to get the result into activity or fragment, follow the following links,

http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.in/2012/05/intentservice-providing-data-back-to.html

Answer (score 0):

In your service you do

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(yourActionToMatchBroadcastReceiverIntentFilter);
intent.putExtra(RegistrationIntentService.PARAM_OUT, yourText);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In activity register your `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`. Whenever your activity is active the receiver will receive intents from your `IntentService`.

**EDIT**

```
public static class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MapActivity activity;
    public ResponseReceiver(MapActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        activity.regid = intent.getStringExtra(RegistrationIntentService.PARAM_OUT);
        // do whatever you need here
    }
}
```

Comment: I did and received the intent extras in the broadcast receiver. My problem is sending the "text" in my question to the main activity. The broadcast receiver is a nested class in main activity.

Comment: You can pass an activity reference to your broadcast receiver when you register it: `new ResponseReceiver(activity);`. In `onReceive` you can do: `activity.regid = intent.getStringExtra(RegistrationIntentService.PARAM_OUT);`

Comment: Hi, @Gennadii. I added these constructors private MapActivity ma;

        public ResponseReceiver(){}

        public ResponseReceiver(MapActivity act){
        this.ma = act;
        } and onResume I did the following:IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        receiver = new ResponseReceiver(this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter); Unfortunately, When I assign the "text" in the onReceive method: MapActivity.regid = text, regid is null. "text" is populated with id like I am supposed to get.

Comment: I don't follow you.. In the first comment you said you received the "text" but you wasn't able to set it to activity. I showed you how to set it to your activity and now you say it is still null? I think I'm missing something here

Comment: When I debug I am getting "type is unknown for 'ma'" in the onResult method of the broadcast receiver. fyi the string regid has a global scope and is declared within the parent class, mapactivity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84616/discussion-between-quantum-droid-and-gennadii-saprykin).